# Migrating filemaker to MySQL problems

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-migration, filemaker

I'm having great difficulty in migrating a data set of about 4750 recordsfrom filemaker to MySQL. I have tried exporting via CSV but it misses out large chunks of data from a couple of columns, and have tried exporting via ODBC, but cannot get the records to copy over to the shadow MySQL table.

I have also tried going the other direction with ODBC by attempting to get Filemaker to import into MySQL using MySQL Workbench but run into an error of UserID missing each time.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated before I take a sledgehammer to the thing.

Thanks!

Comment: If this is a one-off migration consider going via Excel (or open-office calc or whatever). Copy and paste into the spreadsheet (4750 rows should not be too much trouble) then you should be able to spot what is messing with that missing data and can correct it using the spreadsheets tools.

Comment: The question is too generic. You tried all the usual routes and they are all proven to work. I would recommend to concentrate on one option and get it working. E.g. csv export, you have missing columns. May be you need to place this fields on the layout or may be they are coming from related records and your context is incorrect. Or you need to specify your export explicitly using the export dialogue box.

Comment: "*it misses out large chunks of data from a couple of columns*" That's not a sufficient description of the problem (and neither are the others, to tell the truth). My suggestion at this point would be to open the file, **show all records**, export the records (as CSV or Merge would be fine at this point) - and if anything is amiss, describe it **exactly**.

Comment: @Giles Using Excel as an interim format is thoroughly unrecommended. It can change your data!

Comment: @michael.hor257k - This is already happening in the import or data would not be going missing. Also this is migrating from what is likely to be an incompatible data set to begin with, hence Excel thoroughly recommended as you can at least review and modify the data before dumping it on mysql. Much better than simply hoping mysql will somehow understand your source data and get it right first time.

Comment: Mark, in your question you said younrun into an error "UserID missing". Are there any constraints on the mysql columns and are any of them different than the constraints in their FileMaker equivalent? Also, could you update your question to include a description of the FileMaker fields and their corresponding mysql column, specifically each field name, type, and any constraints (e.g. `NOT NULL`)? If you're getting partial imports and errors about missing values it makes me think the constraints need to be adjusted on the mysql columns.